# MAC - Cordova error after installing Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, cordova

On Mac os - Cordova stoped working after installing Android Studio (4.4.1)

NOTE: it was working previous to the installation

With the following errors:

```
The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

And (After the first one was solved)

```
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android PATH changes and was not updated by the cordova, I had to do:

1. update PATH env var

   touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile

add the lines:

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/Users/%USR%/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

2. update local.properties under `platforms/andorid` and `platforms/android/CordovaLib` (line 10) to

   sdk.dir=/Users/%USR%/Library/Android/sdk

where %USR% is your user name