# MAC - cordova project fail after installing Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, cordova

in continuation to [MAC - Cordova error after installing Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729624/mac-cordova-error-after-installing-android-studio)

On Mac os - Cordova project stopped working after installing Android Studio (4.4.1)

NOTE: it was working previous to the installation

I had some error when trying to do `cordova build` which 
I managed to solved (see [MAC - Cordova error after installing Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729624/mac-cordova-error-after-installing-android-studio))

but I'm still cannot run the project on the device.

I've installed the latest cordova (5.4.0) and when I'm running the project I get in logcat `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined`

the line code that fails is `this.device_id = window.device.uuid;`

this line was working previously so it seems that Cordova doesn't load properly.

any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova prepare
```

then refresh the proj and run it (in eclipse)

than I add to delete the project from android studio and re-import it.

NOTE: you might also need to remove/add org.apache.cordova.console plugin