# MAC - how to sync cordova project in android studio

Tags: android, macos, cordova

in continuation to [MAC - cordova project fail after installing Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730497/mac-cordova-project-fail-after-installing-android-studio/33730569#33730569)

I was finally able to run the Cordova project in android studio, but when I change the html/js code in the Cordova project, the change doesn't sync with the copy of the code in android studio.

Is there a way to automatically sync the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `%locationOfStudioProjects%/%cordovaProjName%/src/main/assets` 
delete www folder and do

```
ln -s %locationOfCordova%/platforms/android/assets/www www
```

where

- %locationOfStudioProjects% is the location of android studio proj
- %cordovaProjName% is the name of the cordova proj (start with lower case)
- %locationOfCordova% is the location of the cordova proj

This will create a symbolic link to the corodova www folder and will keep the android studio proj in sync.

NOTE: there is no need to do any thing for xcode since it sync automatically (at least on my env)

Answer (score 1):

In my root www-folder I have two objects:

- index.html
- assets (js-, css-files)

I link these object with symlinks to platforms->android->assets->www

For iOS I use shell scripts in Xcode (Build Phases) to copy the content of the root www-folder to the iOS www-folder.

The shell scripts looking like:

```
cp -R /Users/myUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/www/assets/ /Users/myUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/platforms/ios/www/assets/
cp /Users/myUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/www/index.html /Users/myUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/platforms/ios/www/index.html
```